# Logging out users in teardown during k6 test

Tags: k6

I have a K6 performance test which runs with multiple virtual users and logs in a application user during the test.

Once the test is complete, I want to call our application to logout the users.

At first I thought I could use a SharedArray to gather a list of the users to later logout in teardown, however I've confirmed SharedArray is immutable.

Other suggestions I've seen are to have the virtual users write out to an external system like a database to store which users got accessed. However I believe this will add a lot of latency by writing to the DB.

How can get the list of user ids from my application who had the test run on in the K6 teardown?

I’ve tried adding the http application logins to the setup function, but it seems on the second request it has a problem possibly related to cookies. How can I setup the cookies in the setup properly?

Comment: Where do you log in your users? Can you perform the login in the `setup()` function? `teardown()` may use data produced by `setup()`. `SharedArray` cannot be modified (it's readonly) and is not shared across processes. A KV store such as Redis might help with storing the users, if the login happens as part of the actual test function.

Comment: If I setup the users in the setup() function is there a way to use those same users in the main function, or track which users they are? I've been thinking if there is some way to leverage using passing the `data` from setup() to teardown(). Thanks

Comment: Yes, data from setup can be passed to the default test function and the teardown function: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73458542/112968

Comment: I'm troubleshooting an issue where it seems like the setup can make only one http post for an application login before having an issue which looks like it's related to cookies, or sessions. The same multiple logins work in the default function though. Is there something special about the way the `setup` makes http calls, possibly related to virtual users?

Comment: `setup` is only called _once_ per test, not per VU. If you want to send multiple HTTP requests, you need a loop and keep track of the cookies manually to be then picked up by the test function.

Comment: That must be what I was missing with the cookie tracking. How do you keep track of the cookies manually? I’ve added a bounty to the question, if you want to provide a short write up there can give credit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform the login for all users in the `setup()` function, collect all cookies and then pass them to the default test function.

```
export function setup() {
  const cookies = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < number_of_users; ++i) {
    const jar = new http.CookieJar();
    const res = http.post(
      ...,
      JSON.stringify({username:..., password:...}),
      { jar });

    cookies[i] = jar.cookiesForURL(res.url);
  }
  return { cookies };
}
```

You can either compute/generate the usernames and passwords based on the user number or use a [JSON file that you read into a `SharedArray`](https://k6.io/docs/examples/data-parameterization/#from-a-json-file) in your init context.

This allows you to extract and set the user-specific cookie in your test function per VU:

```
export default function(data) {
  const cookies = data.cookies;
  const cookie = cookies[__VU % number_of_users]; // get cookie for user

  http.cookieJar().set(your_domain, cookie_name, cookie[cookie_name]);

  http.get(...); // uses the cookies that were set in the line above
}
```

Eventually, you want to log out the users again:

```
export function teardown(data) {
  for (let cookie of data.cookies) {
    http.post(..., { cookies: {
      cookie_name: cookie[cookie_name]
    } });
  }
}
```

You can also import the `k6/execution` module which provides access to a unique VU id and use that instead of the global `__VU`.

I have used such an approach with great success in several projects.

Alternatively, it is possible to log in each VU in the first iteration (without a `setup` function):

```
import exec from 'k6/execution';

export default function() {
  if (exec.vu.iterationInInstance == 0) {
    // perform login
    return;
  }

  // here your actual load test code
}
```

Additional resources:

- https://community.grafana.com/t/unique-login-for-each-virtual-user/99596
- https://community.grafana.com/t/how-do-i-parameterize-my-k6-test/96440
- https://community.grafana.com/t/when-parameterizing-data-how-do-i-not-use-the-same-data-more-than-once-in-a-test/99720/16
- https://k6.io/docs/examples/data-parameterization/#retrieving-unique-data
- https://github.com/grafana/k6-learn/blob/main/Modules/III-k6-Intermediate/10-Using-execution-context-variables.md#generating-unique-data